# The max size malloc can allocate?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

my os is arch linux 64 bit.

free -m result below

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32172      31909        262          0        119      13054
-/+ buffers/cache:      18735      13436
Swap:          258        258          0
```

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257329
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257329
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

the kenerl option overcommit_memroy is 0

But when i try to use malloc to allocate 2G bytes ,i fail for the reason:Cannot allocate memory?

Comment: malloc() argument is a SIZE_T, the range of which is [O,SIZE_MAX]. The value of SIZE_MAX depends on the implementation, but you may want to take a look at <limit.h> to see the limit which fits to your configuration.

Comment: The total size of physical memory is  32GB， and i had allocate 4GB success before.So i think the 2GB is not out of the size_t limit ion.

Comment: What's "before" ? Did you change anything which might explain why you cannot redo this operation ?

Comment: Here's a thing to check, besides the kernel limits (which you already did): look for things like apparmor and SELinux, I think that they can enforce quotas in these things. Also look for quotas in general in linux, you might have some sort of enforcer running.And last try to see what happens if you flush the cached memory.

Comment: I have checked my os, app armor and Selinux are disable

Answer (score 3):

It could be anything, actually. It may have worked before because the free memory was all contiguous, and now the free memory isn't, or it might be that your memory request fails the heuristics being used.

see this link here - http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/08/tweaking-linux-kernel-overcommit.html - for more information on turning the overcommit know.

Basically:

- 0 = system heuristically determines whether an overcommit is allowed
- 1 = always overcommit (even if out of address range, so rather stupid if you ask me)
- 2 = never overcommit past certain constraints